# Nextjs fails to find valid build in the '.next' directory in production node_env

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, next.js

I am running my app in docker, but my production build and start script fails only in docker environment. Although node_env development works well in docker environment.

Here is my script that fails to make a production build and start a server. I am using nodemon and babel

```
"build:prod": {
      "command": "babel ./src/server/ -d server --presets es2015,stage-2 && next build src",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
    },
    "start:prod": {
      "command": "PORT=3000 nodemon --watch ./src/server/ ./src/server/server.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
    }
```

But when I give same command in docker environment:

```
FROM node:8-alpine

COPY package.json /tmp/package.json

RUN cd /tmp && npm install

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /opt/app

WORKDIR /opt/app

ADD . /opt/app

RUN npm run build:prod

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

I get the following error in docker:

```
 > better-npm-run start:prod
site_1      | 
site_1      | running better-npm-run in /opt/app
site_1      | Executing script: start:prod
site_1      | 
site_1      | to be executed: PORT=3000 NODE_ENV=production nodemon --watch ./src/server/ ./src/server/server.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2 
site_1      | [nodemon] 1.17.3
site_1      | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
site_1      | [nodemon] watching: /opt/app/src/server/**/*
site_1      | [nodemon] starting `babel-node ./src/server/server.js --presets es2015,stage-2`
site_1      | false 'production'
site_1      | > Could not find a valid build in the '.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
site_1      | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I would appreciate any help and would be nice to know what  I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did yout try adding the ```next build src``` bit to the prod command?

Comment: Why using `nodemon` and not the `next start` command?

Comment: have you solved this issue yet? My docker-compose does not build .next in docker file

Comment: Try changing the production directory from `.next` to something without a starting period, perhaps `_next`.

Comment: Why do you have to copy & install node_modules in /tmp, and copy back to WORKDIR? Usually, WORKDIR automatically creates the directory while running dockerfile command. And also, did you check the message while building the docker image, is there any abnormal message?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the `.next` directory is not being copied from your host

```
ADD . /opt/app
```

Will also add the `.next` directory you had on host. I would add `.dockerignore` and add `.next` to the same. And then build and run again

Comment: It is done already. It was never uploaded to the docker environment from the beginning.

Comment: Then you need provide a minimal repo to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2):

As this issue has gotten quite a few extra votes over time, let me elaborate a bit on a few things you might want to take into account when facing the above problem.

**Version**

Please refer to the official [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs#system-requirements) where Vercel lists Node.js version `10.13 or later` as a requirement.

**Using hardened images for production**

I would also recommend using images that are production hardened and proven to be secure. It's considered good practice to use open source images like those of Bitnami ([why?](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-node#why-use-bitnami-images), [example](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-node/tree/master/example)). Note that this will solve your problem, as now you no longer use any of your local files.

**Guarantee build integrity**

Recommend ignoring `node_modules` along with any build artifacts like `.next` in your `.dockerignore` file and mounting the cache folder for `yarn` or `npm` during build time. That way you can be sure to generate `node_modules` with the correct OS bindings for your image.

Answer (score 0):

Check your .dockerignore

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install pm2 -g
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
RUN npm install --production

# Show current folder structure in logs
RUN ls -al -R

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For production using nextjs use the below commands

```
npm run build && npm run start
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update from 2022**

Please check the official example from vercel how to use nextjs and docker: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker

They don't use `npm run start`, instead `node server.js`

Don't just copy Dockerfile... Look in next.config for `standalone` parametr, and package.json for nextjs version.

In next js 12.1.6 next.config should be:

```
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true
  }
}
```