# NextJS cannot find a valid build in the '.next' directory

Tags: node.js, heroku, next.js

I looked at the following question before asking this one but I believe mine is different because I am not using Docker: [Nextjs fails to find valid build in the '.next' directory in production node_env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676338/nextjs-fails-to-find-valid-build-in-the-next-directory-in-production-node-env)

I also tried [this](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2691) approach of removing the '.next' folder but still get the same issue.

After fixing a host of other issues, I am down to one I cannot seem to resolve.  When I try to deploy to Heroku I keep getting the following error:

```
node server.js

Could not find a valid build in the '.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "StarterApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.4.1"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "next": "^4.2.3",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "node-gyp": "^3.7.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "rebuild": "^0.1.2",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.2",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.79.1",
    "sha3": "^1.2.2",
    "solc": "^0.4.24",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.3",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.34"
  }
}
```

Server.js file:

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const next = require('next');

const app = next({
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
});

const routes = require('./routes');
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app);

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(handler).listen(5000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Ready on localhost:5000');
  });
});
```

The app deploys without issue locally but I get this error when deploying to Heroku.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to create a build first. Run "next build" before "npm start"

Comment: HEY! My server file looks identical. You didn't happen to be taking Stephen Griders Ethereum/Solidity course were ya? If so I have some automation of compile/deploy you should check out.

Comment: @NikHammer-Ellis Sorry for the long delay! Somehow missed this! Where can I check it out? Thanks!

Answer (score 129):

```
npm run build
```

then

```
npm run start
```

solved my problem.

Comment: Why do I need to build everytime tho?

Comment: @NecmettinSargın because sometimes we delete the .next directory mistakenly so in that case, we can create that folder with the build command.

Comment: @NecmettinSargın we need to `npm run build` everytime to update the changes. A good option is to use `npm run dev` instead of `npm start`. It builds and start the proj at the same times.

Answer (score 26):

First

```
npm run-script build
```

Then

```
npm run start
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! please elaborate more or share few details about your answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to see the commenter didn't elaborate, but one thing's for sure: in my Windows 10 environment, using the official create-next-app, his answer is the only one here that worked.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this which builds and starts the project -

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know in nextJs `npm start` only start the project not build. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 6):

Just see the error carefully:

```
Error: Could not find a production build in the 'E:\Developer's Area\weatherteller\.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before s    at Server.readBuildId (E:\Developer's Area\weatherteller\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:146:355)
    at new Server (E:\Developer's Area\weatherteller\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:3:120)
    at createServer (E:\Developer's Area\weatherteller\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:2:638)
    at start (E:\Developer's Area\weatherteller\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:1:323)
    at nextStart (E:\Developer's Area\weatherteller\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-start.js:19:125)
    at E:\Developer's Area\weatherteller\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next:27:115
```

while running

```
npm start
```

It's not able to locate the production build which is required to launch the next app. While creating next app using

```
npm install next react react-dom --save
```

.next folder was not created so you need to create the .next folder first using

```
npm build
```

which will consist of all your production build files.

After npm build the folder will be created and  you can run your app using

```
npm start
```

Also, make sure these scripts are in your next app

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
```

Hope this resolves your error

Answer (score 0):

NextJS building **may** be (depending on your project size), be extremely large, something that can cost you money during deploys.
You can apply the following to your `package.json`

```
{
    "script": {
        "build": "next build",
        "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
        "start": "next start"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when trying to start a production server from the build directory after setting.

```
  distDir: 'build',
```

actual error

> Error: Could not find a production build in the '/home/username/awesome-app/build/build' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id

and my start command

```
$ next start build
```

so I moved the next build directory to another directory named build and it works, and if you are using environment variable put that file inside the build directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once.

First, remove **package-lock.json** or **yarn.lock** files and **node_modules** folder and make sure you install all the packages again with the `yarn` command.
I had to run `yarn build` first and then the `yarn start` command was working fine afterward.

Also if the currently used port is taken by another app you will have issues running your dev environment. You can easily fix that by going into the package.json file and modifying the "dev" script like this: `"dev": PORT=7080 next dev"`.

Also possibly you are mixing Next.js with React because in Next.js you should use `yarn dev` to start your project for development instead of yarn start.

I hope this was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the node version using nvm (node version manager):

```
nvm install 16.17.0
nvm use 16.17.0
```

If you use Windows 10, visit https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nvm-for-windows-how-to-download-and-install-node-version-manager-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

In my case I specified a custom port for NextJs (shown in bellow) and that was the reason I got this error.

this is how i set a custom port `npm start -p 3001` ❌
this is how it should be: 1. change the port in **package.json** file scripts section from `next start` to `next start -p 3001` ✔️

or

you can just use **yarn** and pass the argument just like this `yarn start -p 3001` ✔️

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest node version and you can delete it.next file