# ENOENT: no such file or directory .. NO BUILD_ID

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, next.js

> next start

Debugger attached.
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Janani\ticket-app.next\BUILD_ID'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Janani\ticket-app\.next\BUILD_ID'
}
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

this error is repeating again and its happening for every project... i dont know the BUILD_ID. can you help me in this error

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ran `next start` without first running `next build`

Answer (score 6):

the first, you run:

```
npm i
```

then:

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 2):

The NO BUILD_ID which is contained in the .next folder is missing so it must first be generated with the command:

```
next run build
```

Then you can run :

```
next start
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have package.json in your directory
2. Follow the instructions in [NEXTJS cannot find '.next' directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947389/nextjs-cannot-find-a-valid-build-in-the-next-directory)